# How can I fix this AOSP build error for Oreo?

Tags: java, android, android-source, android-8.0-oreo

I'm trying to build the AOSP (Oreo) for the Nexus 5x. I am building on Ubuntu 14.04.

I went to https://source.android.com/source/requirements and installed all of the requirements. I even uninstalled my version of OpenJDK8 (161) in favor of the 45 version on the site. By using sudo update-alternatives --all, I made sure all of my java related commands point to this version of java 8.

I got the binary preview blobs from https://developers.google.com/android/blobs-preview and untar'd/ran after getting the AOSP.

From the build numbers page https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers I found the build for the nexus 5X is OPR6.170623.013, corresponding to branch android-8.0.0_r4.

So, I repo init -b android-8.0.0_r4, followed by a repo sync, followed by extracting my binary images (which placed them in vendor, as expected). Then I did a lunch, selecting aosp-bullhead-userdebug (option 25), and then make -j8.

After over an hour of building, the build fails (81 errors) on many of the java files with the following error.

"error: unmappable character encoding for UTF-8 // ? 2016 and later: Unicode, Inc. and others."

Does anyone know how I can resolve this build error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
rm -rf out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES
make -j16
```

The answer is modified from page [Problems building android-8.0.0_r4 branch](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/5K9KAXxWi7w), and it works for me(android-8.1.0_r15)